# Reusing regression or machine learning model in subsequent years

Tags: remote-sensing, regression, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, machine-learning

I have collected high-resolution UAV imagery and leaf area index (LAI) plot data. I plan on creating a model which uses my ground-based LAI to establish a relationship or train my UAV imagery. I will try simple linear regression and more complex machine learning algorithms (eg. random forest).

If I create a model with a strong relationship between ground LAI and my UAV imagery, is it possible to only collect UAV imagery in subsequent years and use the old model to train my new data?